# Unexpected Token JSON.parse

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I am trying to parse this text coming from server

```
var s = "{\"server\":DSL01,\"item\":101,\"data\":[[1357849366000,null],[1357849485000,null]}";
JSON.parse(s);
```

In the console I get following error,
Unexpected token D

I need to convert this into a json object.

Comment: It is a JSON string. You mean you want a JavaScript object. If it doesn't pass [JSONLint](http://jsonlint.com/), it's probably not valid JSON.

Answer (score 3):

Because `DSL01` should be a string, and therefore wrapped in `""`

```
"{\"server\":\"DSL01\",\"
```

Also, you lack a `]` on the last part, for closing `data` array.

I suggest you programmatically create your JSON rather than hand-crafting it. That way, you don't make such errors.

Comment: I can't bring that as a string right now. This is what the server returns. Any alternative ?

Comment: Your server is returning garbage. If you can't fix the server, you'll have to hack around and fix it manually before `JSON.parse` can handle it.

Comment: @lostpacket You can't fix a flat tire by blowing more air to it. Fix the server to resolve this issue.

Comment: Ok. Got it. I apologize for insisting a solution.

Comment: Until there's `JSON.parse.justDoIt.please()` you're subject to the [Garbage In, Garbage Out Rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garbage_in,_garbage_out).